# Vastly different size of directories in deja-dup and back in time?

Tags: deja-dup, backintime

I have used deja-dup for years. Today I've installed Back in Time. Both deja and BIT have backed up my /home today. (only object backed up is /home)

Nautilus shows the deja-dup files at 29gig. The BIT files are at 26gig. Why the difference?

I ask this as after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 and losing Unity, I had to "delete" Gnome and restore Unity to get Gourmet Recipe Manager to work. I think deja may have restored corrupted objects to the 18.04 (but I'm guessing). Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Deja dup uses deduplication type of backup while BIT does file-based increments. Meaning that the files you modify are not removed from your backups by dejadup as long as you have old snapshots that have references to it. If you just started using BIT then it won't have references to files you may have deleted from your home folder while dejadup does.